# Python memory management for list()

Tags: python

I'm creating a tuple, and then converting it to a list with the code:

```
y=("hello","the","world")
y=list(y)
```

Does python simply mark the objects as now mutable and reachable through the label y, or does it create a complete copy of every object, add these to the new list structure, and then delete the original immutable objects?

Cheers

Comment: There's a third choice.  Copy the *references* to the original objects.  Please **update** your question to allow for something other than your two assumptions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

During the execution of the line

```
y = list(y)
```

the following happens:

1. The right-hand side gets evaluated.  This includes creating a new list object.  The list object is filled with the items of the tuple object passed to the constructor.  These items are not copied.  Rather their reference count is increased, and references to these items are added to the new list object.
2. The newly created list object is assigned to the name on the left-hand side (`y`).  This includes first unassigning the name, which results in decreasing the reference counter of the tuple object `y` pointed to before.  Since there are no more references to this tuple object, it is deleted.  Finally, `y` is set to point to the new list object.

Answer (score 10):

You can find out by inspecting the `id` of each object.

Here are the results from my run.

```
y=("hello","the","world")
id(y), [id(i) for i in y]
(18627040, [21912480, 21964056, 21910304])

y = list(y)
id(y), [id(i) for i in y]
(21905536, [21912480, 21964056, 21910304])
```

As you can see the objects are the same.

**Update:** Sven Marnach explains *how and why* of it perfectly. Just for reference, I did more tests for other types of objects.

For an object

```
class C: pass
x = (C(), C(), C())
id(x), [id(i) for i in x]
(18626400, [19992128, 19992008, 19991328])
x= list(x)
id(x), [id(i) for i in x]
(21863560, [19992128, 19992008, 19991328])
```

For a list

```
z = ([], [], [])
id(z), [id(i) for i in z]
(18627040, [21908016, 21907136, 21908536])
z = list(z)
id(z), [id(i) for i in z]
(18614992, [21908016, 21907136, 21908536])
```

For a list of lists

```
p = ([[], []], [[], []], [[], []])
id(p), [[id(i) for i in j] for j in p]
(18627040, [[21919504, 21895808], 
            [21894608, 21895008], 
            [19991008, 19789104]])
p = list(p)
id(p), [[id(i) for i in j] for j in p]
(19800352, [[21919504, 21895808], 
            [21894608, 21895008], 
            [19991008, 19789104]])
```

Comment: Using strings is not a good way to test that. Strings with the same contents are usually re-used in CPython since they are immutable.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I did more testing with other types of objects. I all cases the object `id`s are the same. I am not sure I understand your comment completely. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't do deep copying, unless you explicitly ask it to. So the result will be a new, mutable list, containing references to the exact same objects as those you put in the tuple.

Note that the objects in the tuple themselves were always mutable. It's only the tuple of strings that's immutable, i.e. you cannot add/remove objects to the tuple, but you can always access and change objects *inside* a tuple.

Comment: They weren't since strings are immutable.

Comment: @ThiefMaster You're right, in this specific example they aren't. But in the general case, if your objects are mutable to start with, they would be still be mutable if you store [references to] them in a tuple.